# My roommate's short riddle

Tags: riddle, wordplay, lateral-thinking

My roommate (rm) this morning suddenly give me this riddle,

> rm: Hi, good morning! I have a nice riddle for you
>   me: Seriously? Isn't this too early?
>   rm: 'mon, just guess who I am
>
> You change me once, You'll find me on your phone or next to it
>   You change me twice, You'll find me on the sea or behind it
>   You don't change me, because you trust me
>   You can change me, because I trust you
>   They said, those two things that make me exist
>
> Who am I?

Comment: rm: "c'mon, just guess who am I :)" me: "You are my roommate dude. That wasn't hard"

Comment: Did this actually happen, or is this a scenario you came up with yourself? (It would be funny if it were the former, hahah.)

Comment: Does it have something to do with mirror, or reflection? or just light?? :) Im sure it does :D

Comment: @DevMoutarde nope :)

Comment: Is the "wordplay" tag significant?  Because my answer below seems to be the only one utilizing wordplay.  All of the other answers treat this as a simple riddle.

Comment: Could "on the sea or behind it" be phrased differently, or is that precise wording correct? I ask because it doesn't make sense for something to be "behind the sea", so I am wondering if it is a mistranslation or if I just haven't figured out the wordplay yet.

Comment: @David K rot13(lrf, npghnyyl "vg" vfa'g ersre gb "gur frn")

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Inspired by the answer of @JaredLovin, I believe the answer is

> wife

You change me once, You'll find me on your phone or next to it

> The wordplay tag applies here.
>  "On your phone": Wif**e** -> Wif**i**
>  "or next to it": Wi**f**e -> Wi**r**e (solved by @guillau4)

You change me twice, You'll find me on the sea or behind it

> Again, wordplay.
>  "On the sea": W**if**e -> W**av**e
>  "Or behind it": **W**i**f**e -> **T**i**d**e or W**if**e -> W**ak**e  (solved by @pt314)

You don't change me, because you trust me

> Normally, someone becomes someone else's wife for the person she is. Trust is a big part of that.

You can change me, because I trust you

> Because trust plays such an important role, trying to change your wife is typically for the better.

They said, those two things that make me exist

> Mutual trust or husband & wife?

The 3 introductory lines might hint at

> that this is more than just a roommate. Given that it is so early, the two may still be lying in bed together, slowly waking up.

Comment: Late to this, but "They said, those two things that make me exist," is probably a reference to the fact that both of them said "I do," the two things that makes her a wife.

Answer (score 13):

Could you be. Just for fun :p

> **Shorts**?

You change me once, You'll find me on your phone or next to it.

> A clumsy room mate throws shorts wherever he likes after removing it or changing it -even on phone or sometimes next to it

You change me twice, You'll find me on the sea or behind it.

> There can be many scenarios - I'll leave up to reader's imagination :p

You don't change me, because you trust me.

> Obviously we trust shorts that it will do its job of covering (and won't torn etc) :p

You can change me, because I trust you.

> But yes you change also

They said, those two things make me exist.

> Shorts has two openings to easily insert your legs inside-two legs make it exist. It is made up of cloth and elastic. :p

---

**Title:**

My roommate's short riddle.

> It is short - see **shorts**

**Conversation:**

rm: Hi, good morning! I have a nice riddle for you.

> **Morning** is a time to change shorts

me: seriously? Is this not too early?

> **Describes** some prefer to not change shorts so early in the morning

rm: c'mon, just guess who am I :)

> **c'mon**, is the *short* form of come on

Comment: Hello! Welcome to the **Puzzling Stack Exchange**! Congratulations on your very first answer — and it was a good one too! I have reached my daily voting limit, so I cannot upvote your answer. In the meantime, if you are still active, you might want to visit the [**Help Center**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help) if you haven't already. As you have not asked any questions yet, I advise you to look at [this section](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) in particular. Otherwise, keep puzzling! $$\stackrel{\bullet\,\bullet}{\smile}$$

Comment: I really laugh for this answer :)) but sorry this is not intended answer, and the title and the conversation are not part of a hint/clue

Comment: @malioboro Yes, I'll keep an eye here to see the real answer :)

Answer (score 11):

Answer:

> Roommate or to be more precise **rm**

You change me once, You'll find me on your phone or next to it

> change the r in **rm** to **am** and you will see it on your phone or on your alarm clock that is sitting next to it.

You change me twice, You'll find me on the sea or behind it

> change the a in **am** to **pm** you would have changed it twice and you will find it on the other side of the planet which could easily be in a body of water

You don't change me, because you trust me

> You trust your roommate so you wont change your **rm** with someone else.  An alternate: **PM** is not only short for Post Meridiem, it is also short for Prime Minister so don't change it.  Hopefully you trust your prime minister.

You can change me, because I trust you

> You can change the acronym **rm** you use to describe/address him to something else, because your roommate is trusting you will not start calling him by something silly or derogatory. First alternate: You can change the m in **pm** to **pc** to get personal computer.  Personal computers trust you when you open it up and start changing parts in it.  Second alternate: Change the m in **pm** to **pz**, to get puzzle.  malioboro is trusting us with swapping letters in this puzzle to come up with a solution.

They said, those two things that make me exist

> R and M without them **rm** cannot exist

Other notes:

> I strongly suspect that I missing some other acronym variations for the change me parts that would make for a better answer.  Like tm being trademark, which is something you do not change.

Comment: you've intrepret correctly the "change" part! but from "rm" to "pm" you can change it in one way. And I think your second explanation it's not really fit, rm is not the answer :)

Answer (score 10):

I think the answer is

> LOCK

You change me once, You'll find me on your phone or next to it

> LOCK -> **C**LOCK
>  Most phones have clocks on them, or you can have a clock on your desk

You change me twice, you'll find me on the sea or behind it

> CLOCK -> **D**OCK or LOCK -> **DU**CK
>  Docks and ducks are both found on bodies of water including seas.  They both can also be found along the edges of a body of water and thus are behind it.

You don't change me, because you trust me

> You trust your locks to keep you safe, so you don't need to change them

You can change me, because I trust you

> You can change/unlock a lock because you are trusted with the key

They said, those two things that make me exist

*Not sure on this one either...*

Comment: I'm sorry this is not the correct answer, the question is Who am I :)

Answer (score 8):

Could you be

> **Time**?

You change me once, You'll find me on your phone or next to it.

> If you change the **time** once, you might find the "new" time on your phone or beside it, depending on where your phone is.

You change me twice, You'll find me on the sea or behind it.

> If you change the time **schedule** on your phone (once) and then on your calendar (twice), you might be seeing the sun over the sea or over the **horizon** (behind it), depending on what your schedule is.

You don't change me, because you trust me.

> We trust that a minute is **60 seconds**; an hour is **60 minutes**; and that every four years we have a **leap year**.

You can change me, because I trust you.

> We invented the unit of time. Time is all around us, but humans invented the duration of a **second**, and its definition. It is, on some level, our own creation, and it has no choice but to trust us. We are all beings of time; our lives move forward in time.

They said, those two things make me exist.

> Yes, and that is exactly what I said, too. It is because of us that we can **measure** time and **understand its existence**.

---

**Title:**

My roommate's short riddle.

> It is short; it takes a short **period of time** to read it.

**Conversation:**

rm: Hi, good morning! I have a nice riddle for you.

> **Morning** is a point in time.

me: seriously? Is this not too early?

> **Describes** what point in time, morning is.

rm: c'mon, just guess who am I :)

> **c'mon**, meaning "don't **waste your time** and get on with the riddle."

Comment: I really like how you explain the last three clues! but your first and second explanation I think it doesn't really fit :( and sorry TIME is not the intended answer

Comment: and the title and the conversation are not really hint/clues :)

Comment: @malioboro yes, those were the hardest. I thought about this riddle for about $40$ minutes and could not find an answer, though this was my best bet. I thought the conversation was part of the clues because it was included in the sandbox, but that's ok. Keep making more riddles like this one! :)

Answer (score 6):

Note the `wordplay` tag.  Answer:

> LIKE

You change me once,

> LIKE -> LI**N**E

You'll find me on your phone

> refers to lines drawn on the screen, or the connection during a call

or next to it

> "phone line"

You change me twice,

> LIKE -> L**A**KE -> LA**N**E

You'll find me on the sea or behind it

> "sea lane"

You don't change me, because you trust me

> LIKE

You can change me,

> LIKE -> **F**IKE

because I trust you

> "fike" means to flatter.
>  Alternately, LIKE -> L**U*KE, "Trust the force, Luke!"

They said, those two things that make me exist

> {BIKE,DIKE,PIKE,SIKE,LAKE,LOKE,LIFE,LIME} -> LIKE all exist

Comment: yes this is the correct way to intrepret "change" but Like is not the answer, the question is "who am I". "Next" and "behind" doesn't reffer to the word positioning :)

Comment: Given the rot13 comment, what comes to mind for second part of the two changes line is "wake", coming in behind some type of boat.

Comment: *"Trust the Force, Luke!"* $(+1)$

Answer (score 5):

Could it be

> your significant other

You change me once, You'll find me on your phone or next to it

> You just started going out with them, which makes a change in their life. They could be next to your phone physically or have a picture of them as your phone's background/screensaver.

You change me twice, You'll find me on the sea or behind it

> You've dumped them, making a second change to their life, and they will move to a different continent.

You don't change me, because you trust me

> You don't change your SO because you trust them.

You can change me, because I trust you

> They are willing for you to change some aspects about themselves because they trust you.

They said, those two things that make me exist

> Their parents? I dunno.

Comment: +1 your answer is partially correct! and it is close!

Comment: @malioboro Is it best practice on this site to edit my current guess or append my new guess to the answer?

Comment: I think edit is ok, just give a noticable mark so the future viewer will know it was edited

Answer (score 4):

is the answer

> a clock

You change me once, You'll find me on your phone or next to it

> when you change any measurements smaller than a day (seconds, minutes, hours) you have to take another clock as the reference to fix it

You change me twice, You'll find me on the sea or behind it

> when you change any measurements greater than or equal to a day (days, months) you have to take the **sun** as the reference to fix it.

You don't change me, because you trust me

> you don't change your clock's settings as long as you trust it

You can change me, because I trust you

> clocks let users change their settings for many reasons

They said, those two things make me exist.

> clocks exist to keep track of two types of measurements mentioned above

**NOTE**: My answer is the first thing that came to my mind but I couldn't fully reason it. It is highly influenced by @user477343 's reasonings but since OP said his answer is not the intended one I wanted to give it a try.

Comment: of course!  your smart reasonings made my answer possible

Comment: I'm sorry but not the answer, the question is who am I not what am I :)

Answer (score 3):

Is the answer

> a Key?

You change me once, You'll find me on your phone or next to it

> You unlock your phone by entering a key pattern? After you unlock a door, you put the key in your pocket, next to your phone.

You change me twice, You'll find me on the sea or behind it

> Not sure about this one, maybe if you lock something, it becomes unreachable like land beyond the sea?

You don't change me, because you trust me

> You won't get a different key as you know only this one works with the lock

You can change me, because I trust you

> You are the only one that will get a replica as you trust no-one else has a copy

They said, those two things that make me exist

> "SHUT THE DOOR!" Is what you and your girlfriend said when your roommate walked in early in the morning. A key exists to keep a "door shut". You forgot to lock your bedroom door apparently.

Cheers

Comment: I'm sorry the question is Who am I, not What am I :)

Answer (score 3):

Here goes my try, heavily inspired by @emre-Ünsal and @user477343 answers

> You are an Alarm Clock

You change me once, You'll find me on your phone or next to it

> when (you hit snooze / set a time) on your alarm clock you do it on your phone or in a proper alarm clock presumably next to it

You change me twice, You'll find me on the sea or behind it

> No clue, on the sea or behind it... Something related to turning off your alarm and it sounding the next day?

You don't change me, because you trust me

> you don't change your alarm clock because you trust it will wake you up everyday at the same time

You can change me, because I trust you

> you can change it whenever you want

They said, those two things make me exist.

> Alarms + Clocks = Alarms Clocks

Answer (score 2):

Is the answer

> Sand

You change me once, You'll find me on your phone or next to it

> Sand can be changed or converted into a Glass. You can use it either in your phone as LCD display (or a tempered glass cover) or used as a glass (of water or any other liquid).

You change me twice, You'll find me on the sea or behind it

> This glass can be changed or re-converted into sand by breaking it down into particles sized enough to be as small as sand (and removing the sharpened edges by abrasion). Or the broken down glass can be dumped as garbage into the sea (or ocean or waterbody).

You don't change me, because you trust me

> You need not change sand, and can trust to walk over it or do anything with it as is.

You can change me, because I trust you.

> You can change sand to many other things or materials, so sand gives its complete trust to do as you please with it.

They said, those two things that make me exist

> This one I am not so sure but here it goes. Without sand, there would be no soil and in turn no plants and no life forms would exist.

Comment: I'm sorry not the correct answer :) the question is who am I not what am I

Comment: @malioboro: I had also overlooked the 'wordplay' tag as well while answering.

Answer (score 2):

Well, here is my take on it -(partial one)

> You are Mr.

As,

You change me once, You'll find me on your phone or next to it

> You can change *me* to *mr* - that too letters *e* and *r* are next to each other on one's phone(keyboard)

You change me twice, You'll find me on the sea or behind it

> To be provided.

You don't change me, because you trust me

> As, you are a Mister and hence trust-worthy!

You can change me, because I trust you

> To be provided.

They said, those two things that make me exist

> To be provided.

Answer (score 2):

This was a very much square peg in a round hole after the first clue...

> A (secret) code

You change me once, You'll find me on your phone or next to it

> Change a password and you'll receive a [2FA code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-factor_authentication)

You change me twice, You'll find me on the sea or behind it

> Morse code. You can change the signal from dot to dash or dash to dot.

You don't change me, because you trust me

> If a code is trustworthy, there's no need to change it

You can change me, because I trust you

> You can change a code (meaningfully) only if you're able to decrypt it first

They said, those two things that make me exist

?

Comment: nice try, but not the correct answer :) how do you connect "morse code" to "the sea"? and also the question is "who am I" not "what am I"

Comment: @malioboro I knew it was wrong but fancied posting it anyway. + ships use morse code (maybe not so much any more, but still)